# Can I apply a offset with a unix timestamp value?

Tags: javascript

I have a unix timestamp like:

```
1647386880
```

I want to apply -0400 offset to this value, is this possible in javascript w/o any external libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No library needed. If you know a datetime in the unix timestamp format and you just want to adjust it by 4 hours, you can add/subtract as needed.

(presuming the datestamp is in GMT, and you are not worried about DST (without an actual timezone location any DST can't be determined)

-0400 would be minus 4 hours, thus 4x60x60= 14,400.

```
let origDatestamp = 1647386880;
let offsetDatestamp = origDatestamp - 14400;
```

If your offsets will vary, but always be in the standard format you supplied "[-]HHMM", you could create a function to simplify this.

```
function applyOffset(gmtTimestamp, offset){
  return gmtTimestamp + (parseInt(offset) / 100) * 60 * 60;
}
```

Note there was another answer posted that seems to have been removed (it had potential too!) - just note that offsets are typically to the hour, but there are some that are not e.g. https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html e.g. Newfoundland Canada at -0230